# Scraping from Google from R blocked by java

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

In order to find some missing PDFs (and play) I am writing a small script to automatically search and download from Google Scholar.

```
library(rvest);library(XML)
url = (paste0("https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=no&q=",paste(str_split(x$title," ")[[1]], collapse="+")))
# E.g. 
url = "https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=no&q=Power+athletes+and+distance+training:+physiological+and+biomechanical+rationale+for+change"
page <- read_html(url)

results <- page %>% 
html_nodes("a") %>% # Get all notes of type cite. You can change this to grab other node types.
html_text()

# Check all alternative versions from which to choose a link with a potential pdf
 links = html_attr(html_nodes(page, "a"),"href")[which(grepl("versjoner",results))[1]]
 Target = read_html(paste0("https://scholar.google.com",links))

 results <- Target %>% 
 html_nodes("a") %>% 
      html_text()
  pdfTarget = html_attr(html_nodes(Target, "a"),"href")[which(grepl("PDF",results))[1]]

# Replace all special characters in title
filename = gsub("9999","_",paste0(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", paste(x[[1]]$author[[1]]$family,x[[1]]$year,x[[1]]$title,sep="9999")), ".pdf"))
download.file(pdfTarget, destfile = filename, mode="wb")
```

This works for one pdf, but when run in a loop/or one more Google shuts me down, and asks me turn Java on (via the web browser I guess I would be asked to run a "I am not a robot"-test).

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to circumvent a legitimate protection of their terms of service. My recomendation, try to use another paper aggregation suite that has different terms. For example, I never use google for web-scraping, I use bing.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion since posting this question, but thanks for the reply :) I might also test Yahoo.